# vb.net sequential file access

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on finding a way to monitor a folder's files.

I want to get information on what files are used the most in a folder.

I've looked into using vb.net `FileSystemWatcher` but it doesn't seem to contain any classes for this. The articles I've found don't mention anything functions like this. I found one forum that said to use the timestamp from `LastAccess` in `FileSystemWatcher`. But the description doesn't really match that function.

Is there a way in vb.net to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [`FileSystemWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) is indeed the class you want to use.

The msdn documentation contains an example of how to use it.

Just ensure you are setting the [`NotifyFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter.aspx) to use the [`LastAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters.aspx) filter:

```
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess
```

This way you could create an application or service that monitors your folder and count how often each file is accessed.

---

But to have this work, you have to have the **Last Access Time** functionality enabled. By default, this is disabled on Windows Vista and up.

You can enable/disable this by either using this registry key

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\NtfsDisableLastAccessUpdate

or by simply running

> fsutil behavior set disablelastaccess 0

from a command prompt with administrator rights.